# instability of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following simple differential equation ;

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\right)-q_{t}\left(z_{t}-1\right)$$

I know that $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ are positive constants. $q_{t}$ is also a positive varying variable.

I try to think about the instability of this differential equation. When $\frac{dz}{dt}=0$

I will have ;

$$\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\right)=q_{t}\left(z_{t}-1\right)$$

In this case, I have a stable equilibrium of diffential equation only if I ensure the condition $z_{t}>1$ ?

Comment: I suggest converting this to a system of two equations of the first order and inspect the stability in $(z,z_t)$ variables

Comment: @uranix at first, this was a system of two equations that I have converted to one equation. What do you mean by $(z,z_{t})$ ? $z$ is something constant you mean ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the equation. What is $z_t$?

Comment: @uranix I defined $z_{t}=\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{2}}$